# how to restore a PDF file that's been printed 2 pages per page?

Tags: pdf

Gday there, does anybody know a simple way of doing this?

i.e. somebody printed a normal PDF file 2 up, or two pages per page. They sit side by side, so a 100 page document is only 50 pages of 2 per page.

Now I want to restore the original PDF file.

Thanks in advance! And yes, I've already searched here :)

Comment: I presume you mean "printed to a pdf file printer" or do you mean on paper? I'm quite certain there is a way of doing it, but it may not be simple. The [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) project from apache is one of the tools to get access into a pdf structure

Comment: If you want to program, take a look at [Chapter 6: Reusing existing PDF documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) where we N-up a PDF with a picture of the Golden Gate Bridge. Turning a 50 page document into a 100 page document is called 2-upping. It's easy to do through source code, but you're not telling us which programming language you prefer.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple command line tool I could feed a few arguments to. 

And yes, I've got a PDF file already printed with 2 pages in 1, and I want to restore this 50 page PDF to the original 100 page version